# Pipeline error when deploying beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-pipelines

I am in the process of settings up a CI pipeline with azure DevOps. I am running into an error when trying to manually run the pipeline I get the following error:

[image: err]

Am I missing some steps in my pipeline.yml file? Do I need to publish before deploying to Elastic Beanstalk? Here is my azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build- 
aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
solution: '**/*.sln'
buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
inputs:
restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
inputs:
solution: '$(solution)'
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
inputs:
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: BeanstalkDeployApplication@1
inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'mypipelinetest'
    regionName: 'eu-west-1'
    applicationName: 'BookingSys'
    environmentName: 'BookingSys-env'
    applicationType: 'aspnet'
```

BeanstlakDeployApplicaion Error Log (I hope this provides enough information to solve my problem):

```
##[section]Starting: BeanstalkDeployApplication

==============================================================================
Task         : AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application
Description  : Deploys an application to Amazon EC2 instance(s) using AWS Elastic Beanstalk
Version      : 1.5.0
Author       : Amazon Web Services
Help         : Please refer to [AWS Elastic Beanstalk User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) for more details on deploying applications with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

More information on this task can be found in the [task reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/elastic-beanstalk-deploy.html).

####Task Permissions
This task requires permissions to call the following AWS service APIs (not all APIs may be used depending on selected task options and environment configuration):
* autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities
* autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
* autoscaling:ResumeProcesses
* autoscaling:SuspendProcesses
* cloudformation:DescribeStackResource
* cloudformation:DescribeStackResources
* elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion
* elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation
* elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications
* elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironments
* elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents
* elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer
* elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment

The task also requires permissions to upload your application content to the specified Amazon S3 bucket. Depending on the size of the application bundle, either PutObject or the S3 multi-part upload APIs may be used.
==============================================================================
Deployment type set to aspnet
Configuring credentials for task
46da083f-a34f-46a7-a532-e33470f5c4bf exists true
...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint '46da083f-a34f-46a7-a532-e33470f5c4bf'
...endpoint defines standard access/secret key credentials
Configuring region for task
...configured to use region eu-west-1, defined in task.
Configuring credentials for task
46da083f-a34f-46a7-a532-e33470f5c4bf exists true
...configuring AWS credentials from service endpoint '46da083f-a34f-46a7-a532-e33470f5c4bf'
...endpoint defines standard access/secret key credentials
Configuring region for task
...configured to use region eu-west-1, defined in task.
Determine S3 bucket elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-989127099484 to store application bundle
Uploading application bundle d:\a\1\s to object BookingSys/BookingSys-env/s-v1570289695608.zip in bucket elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-989127099484
Upload of application bundle failed with error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read { Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native) errno: -4068, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
##[error]Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
##[section]Finishing: BeanstalkDeployApplication
```

Could it be that I can an incorrect layout of files in my GitHub repo? Here is my Git repository:
https://github.com/craig1990/CampBookingSys-4th-Year-Project

Forigve me if I am missing something simple although this is my first time using Azure DevOps. Can anyone see why I am getting the above error?

Comment: @DanielMann Maybe I am missing some steps in my pipeline.yml file? Do I need to publish before deploying to Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: It looks like you're specifying an incorrect path to your artifact. You're putting the zip file in `$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)`, but not telling the task to look there for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the task output mentions, you have to upload the zip file to an S3 bucket before you can deploy it.

An example is provided [here](https://www.designingforthefuture.com/ci-cd-with-angular-7/). Obviously, you will need to change the below to reflect the names of the files you're using and your AWS resources.

```
- task: S3Upload@1
  displayName: 'S3 Upload: angular-docker-bucket'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS-test'
    regionName: 'us-east-2'
    bucketName: 'angular-docker-bucket'
    sourceFolder: 'elastic-beanstalk'
    globExpressions: output.zip
    createBucket: true

- task: BeanstalkDeployApplication@1
  displayName: 'Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk: angular-docker-test'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: 'AWS-test'
    regionName: 'us-east-2'
    applicationName: 'angular-docker-test'
    environmentName: 'AngularDockerTest-env'
    applicationType: s3
    deploymentBundleBucket: 'angular-docker-bucket'
    deploymentBundleKey: output.zip
    logRequest: true
    logResponse: true
```

Comment: The link provided above is no longer providing anything useful.